# Просьба помочь с рекурсивным обходом данных для построения дерева

Tags: javascript, рекурсия, дерево, обработка-данных

Помогите, пожалуйста, построить правильную структуру из исходных данных.

Необходимо взять исходные данные и сформировать из них вложенную структуру (дерево).
Путь для обхода можно взять из поля "name" каждого элемента nodes.

Как определяется вложенность:
У каждого элемента есть поле name. 
Последняя подстрока справа после слэша в этом поле - это title текущего элемента.
Далее, чтобы получить родителя или потомков данного элемента, необходимо взять соответственно подстроку слева или подстроку справа от него и таким образом накопить аккумулятор, проходясь по каждому элементу.

У одного элемента в исходной коллекции nodes может быть несколько потомков.
Если у элемента потомков нет, то его поле isDirectory === false, в противном случае isDirectory === true.

Отношение родитель - потомок определяется в поле 'name' с одним исключением - элемент с id === 0 - это корень всей структуры, его name уникален и не содержит какой-либо структуры.Таким образом для элементов [{id: 0, name: 'Корень'}, {id: 1, name: 'first/second'}, {id: 2, name: 'first'}] корнем будет являться элемент с id0, а id1 - это его потомок, а id2 - потомок элемента id1. Т.е. результат будет таким:

```html
[
 {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Корень',
    isDirectory: true,
    children: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'first',
            isDirectory: true,
            children: [
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'second',
                    isDirectory: false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
 }
]
```

Как выглядит результирующее дерево - я прикрепил ниже.
Не смог самостоятельно реализовать корректное решение, потому буду благодарен помощи в реализации или хотябы с алгоритмом.

Исходные данные:

```html
const nodes = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "\"Корень\"",
    "createDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:26.95",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:26.95",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 0,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:26.95",
    "audiences": [0, 0, 0, 0]
  },
  {
    "id": 1000831,
    "name": "\"Store/Сегменты для OPS/Сегменты для внешней рекламы/Автодилеры\"",
    "createDate": "2018-12-29T03:04:28.26",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-29T03:04:28.26",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 23511,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2019-01-09T05:48:23.487",
    "audiences": []
  },
  {
    "id": 1000249,
    "name": "\"Store/Сегменты для OPS/Сегменты для внешней рекламы\"",
    "createDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:42.313",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:42.313",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 1490426,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2019-01-09T05:48:04.827",
    "audiences": []
  },
  {
    "id": 1000032,
    "name": "\"Store/Сегменты для OPS\"",
    "createDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:19.48",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:19.48",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 0,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:19.48",
    "audiences": []
  },
  {
    "id": 28473,
    "name": "\"Store\"",
    "createDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:32.733",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:32.733",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 0,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:32.733",
    "audiences": []
  },
  {
    "id": 1000772,
    "name": "\"Store/Сегменты для OPS/Сегменты для внешней рекламы/Cian\"",
    "createDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:05.02",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:05.02",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 30409,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2019-01-09T05:48:20.673",
    "audiences": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2681,
    "name": "\"Сегменты Facetz/Образ жизни/Обзоры",
    "createDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:30.623",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:30.623",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 115379,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2019-01-09T05:48:23.847",
    "audiences": []
  },
  {
    "id": 3840,
    "name": "\"Сегменты Facetz/Образ жизни\"",
    "createDate": "2018-12-11T14:39:46.45",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-11T14:39:46.45",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 0,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2018-12-11T14:39:46.45",
    "audiences": []
  },
  {
    "id": 3811,
    "name": "\"Сегменты Facetz\"",
    "createDate": "2018-12-11T14:39:46.373",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-11T14:39:46.373",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 0,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2018-12-11T14:39:46.373",
    "audiences": []
  }
];
```

```html
const result = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'Корень',
    isDirectory: true,
    children: [
      {
        id: 28473,
        title: 'Store',
        isDirectory: true,
        children: [
          {
            id: 1000032,
            title: 'Сегменты для OPS',
            isDirectory: true,
            children: [
              {
                id: 1000249,
                title: 'Сегменты для внешней рекламы',
                isDirectory: true,
                children: [
                  {
                    id: 1000831,
                    title: 'Автодилеры',
                    isDirectory: false,
                  },
                  {
                    id: 1000772,
                    title: 'Cian',
                    isDirectory: false,
                  }
                ] 
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 3811,
        title: 'Сегменты Facetz',
        isDirectory: true,
        children: [
          {
            id: 3840,
            title: 'Образ жизни',
            isDirectory: true,
            children: [
              {
                id: 2681,
                title: 'Обзоры',
                isDirectory: false
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```html
// Solution
const traverseNodes = (acc, currentNode, index, allNodes) => {
  const path = currentNode.name.split('/');
  const title = path[path.length - 1].replace(/("|')/g, '');
  const id = currentNode.id;

  const currentChildren = allNodes
    .filter(n => n.id !== id)
    .filter(n => n.name.includes(title));

  const isDirectory = currentChildren.length > 0 || id === 0;

  if (isDirectory) {
    return acc.concat([{
      id,
      title,
      isDirectory,
      children: currentChildren.reduce(traverseNodes , [])
    }]);
  } else {
    return acc.concat([{ id, title, isDirectory }]);
  }
};

const result = nodes.reduce(traverseNodes , []);
```

Comment: Почему у вас в данных, в примере, node "Корень" не является корнем а в результате (`const result`) является?

Comment: Потому что таково требование бизнеса. Отношение родитель - потомок определяется в поле 'name' с одним исключением - элемент с id === 0 - это корень всей структуры, его name уникален и не содержит какой-либо структуры.Таким образом для элементов [{id: 0, name: 'Корень'}, {id: 1, name: 'first/second'}, {id: 2, name: 'first'}] корнем будет являться элемент с id0, а id1 - это его потомок, а id2 - потомок элемента id1. Т.е. результат будет таким: https://pastebin.com/BAv9w4Ci

Comment: Прекрасное пояснение, не могли бы вы его добавить в вопрос? Потому что это ну совсем не очевидно)

Comment: Спасибо, добавил)

Answer (score 0):

Есть вот такое решение. Возможно, оно не оптимально.

```js
const nodes = [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "\"Корень\"",
    "createDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:26.95",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:26.95",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 0,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:26.95",
    "audiences": [0, 0, 0, 0]
  },
  {
    "id": 1000831,
    "name": "\"Store/Сегменты для OPS/Сегменты для внешней рекламы/Автодилеры\"",
    "createDate": "2018-12-29T03:04:28.26",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-29T03:04:28.26",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 23511,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2019-01-09T05:48:23.487",
    "audiences": []
  },
  {
    "id": 1000249,
    "name": "\"Store/Сегменты для OPS/Сегменты для внешней рекламы\"",
    "createDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:42.313",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:42.313",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 1490426,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2019-01-09T05:48:04.827",
    "audiences": []
  },
  {
    "id": 1000032,
    "name": "\"Store/Сегменты для OPS\"",
    "createDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:19.48",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:19.48",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 0,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:19.48",
    "audiences": []
  },
  {
    "id": 28473,
    "name": "\"Store\"",
    "createDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:32.733",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:32.733",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 0,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:32.733",
    "audiences": []
  },
  {
    "id": 1000772,
    "name": "\"Store/Сегменты для OPS/Сегменты для внешней рекламы/Cian\"",
    "createDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:05.02",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:05.02",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 30409,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2019-01-09T05:48:20.673",
    "audiences": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2681,
    "name": "\"Сегменты Facetz/Образ жизни/Обзоры",
    "createDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:30.623",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-11T14:40:30.623",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 115379,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2019-01-09T05:48:23.847",
    "audiences": []
  },
  {
    "id": 3840,
    "name": "\"Сегменты Facetz/Образ жизни\"",
    "createDate": "2018-12-11T14:39:46.45",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-11T14:39:46.45",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 0,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2018-12-11T14:39:46.45",
    "audiences": []
  },
  {
    "id": 3811,
    "name": "\"Сегменты Facetz\"",
    "createDate": "2018-12-11T14:39:46.373",
    "updateDate": "2018-12-11T14:39:46.373",
    "folderId": -1,
    "ctnsCount": 0,
    "ctnsCountDate": "2018-12-11T14:39:46.373",
    "audiences": []
  }
];
class Node {
  constructor(id, name, parentName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.parentName = parentName;
    this.children = [];
  }

  get isDirectory() {
    return !!this.children.length;
  }

  static createTree(nodes) {
    const firstNode = nodes.find(f => f.id === 0);
    const rootNode = new Node(firstNode.id, firstNode.name.replace(/"/g, ''))
    nodes = nodes.filter(f => f !== firstNode);
    const flatNodes = nodes.map(m => {
      const splitNames = m.name.replace(/"/g, '').split('/');
      const name = splitNames.pop();
      const parent = splitNames.pop() || rootNode.name;
      return new Node(m.id, name, parent);
    });
    flatNodes.push(rootNode);
    flatNodes.forEach(node => {
      const parentNode = flatNodes.find(f => f.name === node.parentName);
      if (parentNode) {
        parentNode.children.push(node);
      }
    });
    return rootNode;
  }
}

const tree = Node.createTree(nodes);

console.log(tree);
```